# SignalR join/leave group doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple application using SignalR, where I wan't to display different data for different machines, depending on which machine has been chosen by the user

My Hub class looks like this:

```
    readonly ISprayBroadcaster _sprayBroadcaster;
    readonly IWorkRecordRepository _workRecordRepository;

    public SprayHub(ISprayBroadcaster sprayBroadcaster, IWorkRecordRepository workRecordRepository)
    {
        _sprayBroadcaster = sprayBroadcaster;
        _workRecordRepository = workRecordRepository;
    }

    public void Broadcast(string name)
    {
        Process.DataProcess(_workRecordRepository, Clients, name).Wait();
    }

    public void SwapGroup(string previousGroup, string newGroup)
    {
        Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, previousGroup);
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, newGroup);
    }

    public void JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
```

This is how I initialize the hub on the client side and call Broadcast method on it:

```
        $(function () {
            hub = $.connection.sprayHub;
            function init() {
                hub.server.joinGroup("machine1");
                hub.server.broadcast("machine1");
            };

            // Client-side hub method that the server will call
            hub.client.updateData = function (shifts) {
                ViewModel.Measurements(recreateArray(shifts));
            }
            $.connection.hub.start().done(init);
        });
```

Broadcast method goes to the DataProcess method which populates data to the clients from the assigned group:

```
    public static async Task DataProcess(IWorkRecordRepository workRecordRepository, IHubConnectionContext hubClients, string machine)
    {
        var shiftRecords = await workRecordRepository.Records(machine, DateTime.Now).ToList();
        var result = SLGT.Sentinel.Core.Calculations.Shifts(shiftRecords);
        hubClients.Group(machine).updateData(result);
    }
```

At the same time I setup a broadcaster which runs in the loop and feeds clients with appropriate data. This is a broadcast method from the broadcaster which calls the same DataProcess method to populate data for each machine found in the system:

```
    void Broadcast(object state)
    {
        lock (_updateLock)
        {
            if (_updating) 
                return;

            _updating = true;

            var machines = _workRecordRepository.Machines();
            machines.Subscribe(async machine =>
            {
                await Process.DataProcess(_workRecordRepository, Clients, machine);
            });

            _updating = false;
        }
    }
```

Finally when user clicks a button for different machine on the client side I swap the groups for the appropriate data to be displayed for this client:

```
    $(".machineButton").click(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr("id");
        hub.server.swapGroup(previousGroup, name);
        previousGroup = name;
    }
```

Now, when I run this application in my test environment, everything works fine. When I run it on the server, swap between the groups doesn't work correctly, and the client is constantly fed with the same set of data. Why might it be happening? As I said local version works fine so I do not know how to debug it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group management methods (add and remove) are async. If you don't await the returned task then send to the group immediately after you have a race condition such that the client you just added might not receive the message. Also, you should never call .Wait() from in a hub method. Make the hub method async and await it instead.

```
readonly ISprayBroadcaster _sprayBroadcaster;
readonly IWorkRecordRepository _workRecordRepository;

public SprayHub(ISprayBroadcaster sprayBroadcaster, IWorkRecordRepository workRecordRepository)
{
    _sprayBroadcaster = sprayBroadcaster;
    _workRecordRepository = workRecordRepository;
}

public async Task Broadcast(string name)
{
    await Process.DataProcess(_workRecordRepository, Clients, name);
}

public async Task SwapGroup(string previousGroup, string newGroup)
{
    await Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, previousGroup);
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, newGroup);
}

public async Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}
```

Also, is your production environment a single web server or is it a load-balanced farm? If it's a farm you'll need to [configure SignalR scale-out](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr).